# module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'

Tags: python

OS: WIndows 10

```
ssh_command = f"ssh {ssh_username}@{ssh_address} -p {ssh_port}"
ssh_session = pexpect.spawn(ssh_command, encoding='utf-8')
```

Error:

```
(Python310_Services_VENV) C:\UPScripts>python test.py
Trying to establish SSH connection.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\UPScripts\test.py", line 13, in check_power_status
    ssh_session = pexpect.spawn(ssh_command, encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawn'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed ticket in pexpect about this. It seems to be a deliberate change in api by the developers. https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/321#issuecomment-174547577

> If you're on Windows, that's expected. pexpect.spawn has historically used ptys, which are a Unix thing that Windows doesn't have. We chose not to make the same name available on Windows because it couldn't behave quite the same.
> http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html#pexpect-on-windows

From the linked docs:

> Pexpect can be used on Windows to wait for a pattern to be produced by a child process, using pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn, or a file descriptor, using pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn.

> pexpect.spawn and pexpect.run() are not available on Windows, as they rely on Unix pseudoterminals (ptys). Cross platform code must not use these.

> PopenSpawn is not a direct replacement for spawn. Many programs only offer interactive behaviour if they detect that they are running in a terminal. When run by PopenSpawn, they may behave differently.